# Default on-screen keyboard and Onboard show up at the same time on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: 20.04, touchscreen, onscreen-keyboard, onboard

I am relatively new to Linux, but I managed to solve all my issues until this one happened.

I am using a Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu 20.04.3 as a PC with a touchscreen monitor. I have installed Onboard keyboard and added it to Startup Applications and it works nice. However, whenever I open for example LibreOffice Calc, another on-screen keyboard appears. This one looks different and I presume it is the default Ubuntu on-screen keyboard.

I have turned off on-screen keyboard in accessibility options, but it still shows up every time. I don't know how to disable this default on-screen keyboard. It doesn't appear when I connect my physical keyboard, but the whole idea of touchscreen is to avoid the physical keyboard as I only need numbers for running my application.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: I think you mean `caribou`. You could remove it or simply rename its executable file (which makes it easy to activate again). You can also try to block it according to [this link](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1326/block-caribou/). I have **not** tried that blocker.

Comment: Thank you for ideas. Can you tell me where to find caribou executable file?

Comment: UPDATE: When I tried to remove caribou it said: Package caribou is not installed.

Comment: I think it is a mess. You are right, now it is not the explicit program caribou, but seems to be integrated into gnome. You can try according to the following links: https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-virtual-keyboard-linux/ (but check that it is turned off); https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/639929/permanently-and-completely-disable-onscreen-keyboard-for-ubuntu-20-04 and the links from this second link.

Comment: There are workarounds: I tested (in a persistent live Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.3 LTS) to install the meta package `xubuntu-desktop` and got rid of that extra screen keyboard, when running as Xubuntu instead of Ubuntu's Gnome desktop environment. It will probably work with the meta package `lubuntu-desktop` too (and run as Lubuntu. But if your system is new and you have not invested too much work in it, you can make a fresh installation of Lubuntu or Xubuntu, installl `onboard` and work without that extra screen keyloard.

Comment: A fresh installation is a problem for me because I have already spent a lot of time setting up everything I need. Can yo give me some guidance on how to install meta package xubuntu-desktop?

Comment: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop` but please be aware, that you cannot remove [it's components] without causing problems, so your system will live with it alongside `ubuntu-desktop` even if you go back to Ubuntu and Gnome. This is usually not a problem; some extra drive space will be occupied, some applications will have two tools (for example file browser and terminal emulator) ...

Comment: Installing xubuntu didn't solve the problem. Then I tried installing gnome extension block caribou from this link: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1326/block-caribou/ . That did the trick! But thank you very much for assistance!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-) Installing `xubuntu-desktop` is not enough. You must also switch 'session' at the log in screen to Xubuntu. That solved the problem for me, and I *think* that it would solve the problem for you too. But if you want to continue using standard Ubuntu with Gnome, your solution to block caribou is the best alternative.

Comment: I think it would be helpful for other users, if you write 'your own' answer, and after a couple of days click the tick to 'accept' it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two workarounds. One is, as sudodus explained, to install xubuntu desktop and switch session at log in screen to Xubuntu. Second workaround is to install gnome extension block caribou. That way you don't have to switch to Xubuntu if you want to keep using Gnome desktop as I do.

Block caribou extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1326/block-caribou/